# what is the solution of this question on partial differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

what is the solution of this $$\frac{1}{D^2_x-D^2_y}\sin(x-y)$$ please solve, should I move using $\exp(x-y)$ or  any other method is there to solve this for particular integral

Comment: What you wrote is an expression, and not an equation.  (There is no equals sign).  So it cannot be solved.

Comment: ya of course, it's not an equation and I've not mentioned here it is. so I mentioned it as the particular integral of a diff. eqn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u=a\sin(x-y)$. Then
$$
u_{xx}-u_{yy}=-a\sin(x-y)-a\sin(x-y)=-2a\sin(x-y).
$$
Thus a particular solution is
$$
U(x,y)=-\frac{\sin(x-y)}{2}.
$$
Now $V=u-U$ satisfies the Wave Equation $$V_{xx}-V_{yy}=0,$$ which means that $V$ is of the form
$$
V(x,y)=F(x+y)+G(x-y).
$$
Thus the general form of $u$ is
$$
u(x,y)=F(x,y)+G(x,y)-\frac{\sin(x-y)}{2}.
$$

Comment: For your choice $u_{xx}=u_{yy}$, is not it?